# Antlr4 Grammar pattern for Date and Month

Tags: java, antlr4

I am writing some code to find date pattern via antlr4 grammar.
Here is what I have written.

```
DAY             :   ONE_DIGIT | TWO_DIGITS ; 

fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;
ONE_DIGIT       : DIGIT ;
TWO_DIGITS      : DIGIT ONE_DIGIT ;
THREE_DIGITS    : DIGIT TWO_DIGITS ;
FOUR_DIGITS     : DIGIT THREE_DIGITS ;
```

similarly for month. ONE_DIGIT | TWO DIGIT. 
but right now scope of month and day are 0-99 which i dont want.

I want some fragment where day is limited to 1-31 and month 1-12.
I tried some regexes which works in java but those are not working here.

Comment: That won't get you very far. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/antlr/3271/lexer-rules-in-v4/11235/priority-rules#t=201609201606046536708). Parse any number, with a single `NUMBER` rule, then do the validation step *after* the parsing. Or you'll get into trouble at the next step.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I am new to ANTLR, can you please explain in more detail.